# More projections with ogr2ogr?

Tags: gis, projection, ogr2ogr

I'm new to using ogr2ogr and have been wanting to reproject an ESRI Shapefile to NAD83 State Plane Washington North Projection (EPSG:32148) from WGS84.

Ive gotten it to reproject to NAD83 but I can't get it use a Projected Coordinate System. Does it only project Geographic Coordinate Systems?

If that is the case is there another library that will project PCS?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ogr2ogr` options you can reproject the shapefile. Here I have run this command in terminal which gives the desired output.

Traffic shp was in WGS48 EPSG:32643 reference system. After running this command I got NAD83 EPSG:32148 projection.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -t_srs EPSG:32148 -s_srs EPSG:32643 'output.shp'  'trafic.shp'
```

Hope this will help.